Podman container exits immediatly after run
I am running a containter in podman, I used the following containerfile to build the image:
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
CMD ["service", "apache2", "start"]

EXPOSE 8080

After the image is built I run podman run -d -i -t -p 8080:80 myImage, then the container is created and exit immediatly. The container's log show only this:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2.
If I ommit this line CMD ["service", "apache2", "start"] in the containerfile when I build the image, the container remains runnig OK.
My OS is Windows 10 Pro 21H2
What am i doing wrong?

The container command exits, so the container halts. That's the whole point of application containers. What the command did (start Apache) is irrelevant.
If you want something more like a VM or a physical server then you want a system container. Something like incus/lxd/lxc. I don't believe any of those have Windows client apps and VMs packaged up like docker/podman though.
